# GitLab CE clone project by web GUI: fatal: unable to access... Couldn't resolve host ... because password has character "@"

Tags: git, gitlab

I use GitLab CE.
I init a new repo by import URL:

```
https://username:password@gitlab.company.com/group/project.git
```

In my password have a special character `@`. Then error:

```
Cloning into bare repository '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/vydn/myzip.git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:p@ssword@gitlab.company.com/group/project.git': Couldn't resolve host 'ssword@gitlab.company.com/group/project.git'
```

How to use password has character `@` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

- Send `username & password` separately

  ```
  https://github.com/foobar/SparkDataSystem --username <user> --password <pass>
  ```
- Or, you can save your `username` & `password` to reduce the number of time you must type your username/password

  ```
  $ git config credential.helper store
  $ git push http://example.com/repo.git
  Username: <type your username>
  Password: <type your password>

  [several days later]
  $ git push http://example.com/repo.git
  [your credentials are used automatically]
  ```

  [See more](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#_examples)

Comment: It can't apply to my situation. Let's imagine, I want clone repository to repository by WebUI (100%), not use command line (cmd, git bash, terminal, etc.) or local machine in this case. If my password hasn't character `@` no problem. But I change password need many time.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [GitLab CE issue 7986](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/7986)

> As per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), `@` is a special character and needs to be encoded like this:

```
https://xxxx:yyyy%40zzzz@mygit.mycompany.com/hello/
                 ^^^
                  |_ instead of '@'
```